# c++ carriage return & MFC richedit control parsing?

Tags: c++, mfc, carriage-return

I have a richedit control & I've noticed that my MFC richedit.SetWindowText(string) function is parsing "0x0D 0X09" & counting it as a line (ie carriage return) & I'm wondering if this is correct? Following is example of code I'm using.

pseudo code;

```
void DisplayData()
{
    CString str((char*)pfilebuffer, filesize); //pfilebuffer is unsigned char*
    m_RichEdit.SetWindowText(str);
}

void ObtainSelectedLine()
{
    long nLineNum;
    nLineNum = m_RichEdit.LineFromChar(m_RichEdit.LineIndex(-1));
    TRACE(L"%d\n", nLineNum);
}

void CountCarriageReturns()
{
    for(unsigned long i=0 ; i<filesize ; i++ )
{
    if(pbuffer[i] == 0x0A)
    {
        iCarriageReturn++;
    }
}
TRACE(L"iCounter: %d\n",iCarriageReturn);
}
```

ie iCarriageReturn is different to last line of nLineNum. If I take into account 0D09 & also count these it equals number of lines as parsed by SetWindowText().

EDIT: Ultimately what I'm trying to do is get the file position of the caret position, inclusive of any carriage returns etc, but I haven't been able to locate such function.

Any input be geat thanks.

Comment: 0x09 is a tab, it shouldn't affect line breaks. In many environments, a line break can be represented as any of the following: 0D, 0A, 0D0A or 0A0D; not sure if that is the case with RichEdit though.

Comment: Are you using a wrap option for your control? Also: are you using line breaks features? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270412(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The control isn't being word wrapped at all & it is definately creating new line on 0D09. It's doing this on text files either 2 lines long or 2million long. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is get the file position of the caret position, inclusive of any carriage returns, but I haven't been able to locate such function.